# Waiting until slave has been synchronized

Tags: php, mysql, master-slave

Is there any SQL (or PHP command) that can be used to either force a master to propagate changes to slaves and/or wait until the changes have been propagated to all slaves?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `MASTER_POS_WAIT()`. Call this function in an SQL expression on the replica, and it will block (not return) until the replica has executed up to specified log file & position.

```
SELECT MASTER_POS_WAIT('mysql-bin.000042', 8675309);
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/master-pos-wait.html

Answer (score 2):

Standard MySQL replication is asynchronous. You'd have to check the slaves yourself - possible, but there's no built-in command to do all the work for you.

MySQL 5.5 brings [semisynchronous replication](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/replication-semisync.html), which I've no experience with.

There's also synchronous replication via things like Galera. We use a Galera-based variant of MySQL, Percona XtraDB Cluster, at work.